# What is the difference between the receptive field and a patch?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

In this question and answer it is beautifully described what a patch is.

[What's a "patch" in CNN?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309308/whats-a-patch-in-cnn?newreg=fff6c5d3fcdd45b7925365470e503457)

However, for me, following the explanation in the link, it seems like a patch and the receptive field must be the same. Is that true?